# SimpleFramework and ORMLite - Foreign Collections - cannot instantiate

Tags: android, ormlite, foreign-collection

We are using ORMLite 4.41 in our Android app and facing this issue:

Having defined one column in class A:

```
@Element(required = false)
@ForeignCollectionField(eager=true, orderColumnName="Name",
    columnName="TestItems")
public ForeignCollection<TestItem> Test
```

In class B we have defined foreign column:

```
@DatabaseField(foreign=true, foreignAutoRefresh=true,
    columnName="TestItems")
public TestSummary TestItemId;
```

When we run it and it receives the input XML, Serializer.read method is called where the output should be classes filled with foreign keys being initialized.

Unfortunately, it always stops with the exception:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate interface
    com.j256.ormlite.dao.ForeignCollection for field 'Test' public
    com.j256.ormlite.dao.ForeignCollection xxxxxxxx.TestModel$TestSummary.Test
```

Is there any way how to use `ForeignCollection` together with SimpleFramework?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Collection` instead, and I think you should be using `ElementList` instead of `Element`.

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager=true, orderColumnName="Name",
    columnName="TestItems")
@ElementList(required = false)
public Collection<TestItem> Test
```